# how to remove square brackets from particular place in json file in linux using jq

Tags: json, ubuntu, sed, jq

i want to remove square brackets as illustrated in this example:

Input file : file1.json

```
{ "regex_features": [
      [ // This bracket needs to be removed
        {
          "name": "jobname",
          "pattern": "[A-Z]+-[0-9]"
        },
        {
          "name": "project",
          "pattern": "[A-Z]{4}"
        },
        {
          "name": "summary",
          "pattern": "[a-z]+[a-z]+[a-z]{4}"
        },
        {
          "name": "description",
          "pattern": "[a-z]+[a-z]+[a-z]+[a-z]{4}"
        }
      ] // this bracket needs to be removed. 
     ]
}
```

please suggest.

Comment: Will the output remain a valid JSON after the removal?

Comment: Yes it will remain valid json as it is big json file and this is a small part of it from which i need to remove those square brackets as i mentioned.

Comment: jq `.regex_features|=.[0]` should work

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have this file.json:

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "regex_features": [
    [
      {
        "name": "jobname",
        "pattern": "[A-Z]+-[0-9]"
      },
      {
        "name": "project",
        "pattern": "[A-Z]{4}"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

You can use the update assignment operator to replace the list by its first element (which is the inner list):

```
jq '.regex_features|=.[0]' file.json
```

Output:

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "regex_features": [
    {
      "name": "jobname",
      "pattern": "[A-Z]+-[0-9]"
    },
    {
      "name": "project",
      "pattern": "[A-Z]{4}"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Below is the output of the suggested command.
 `{
  "name": "foo",
  "regex_features": [
    [
      {
        "name": "jobname",
        "pattern": "[A-Z]+-[0-9]"
      },
      {
        "name": "project",
        "pattern": "[A-Z]{4}"
      }
    ]
  ]
},
"regex_features": null
}`

Comment: I got it. Thank you. :)

Comment: @VageeshSM please don't forget to mark your question as answered